# numeral.js live formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, numeral.js

I would like to live format an input box with Numeral.js.

I tried something like this.

```
    $('#exchangeInputFirst').keyup(function () { 
//eur formatting
            numeral.language('sk');
            $('#exchangeInputFirst').val(numeral($('#exchangeInputFirst').val()).format('0,0.00$'); 

//to HUF format            $('#exchangeInputSecond').val($('#exchangeInputFirst').val()*$('#first').html());
            numeral.language('hu');
            var string = numeral($('#exchangeInputSecond').val()).format('0,0.00$'); 
            $('#exchangeInputSecond').val(string);
        });
```

The second function is working perfectly (to HUF format), but the first not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the numeral language file:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.5.3/languages.min.js"></script>
```

I cannot reproduce your situation unless I do not include the languages js file. Try your example and hit a key on the first input box:

```js
var a = false;
$('#exchangeInputFirst, #exchangeInputSecond').click(function () {
 $(this).caret(0);
});

$('#exchangeInputFirst, #exchangeInputSecond').keyup(function(){
 if(a == false){
  $(this).val('');
  a = true
 } else {
  numeral.language($(this).data('language'));
  $(this).val(numeral($(this).val()).format('0,0.00$'));
  $(this).caret(0);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.5.3/numeral.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.5.3/languages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/jquery.caret/dist/jquery.caret-1.5.2.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" data-language="sk" id="exchangeInputFirst">
<input type="text" data-language="hu" id="exchangeInputSecond">
```

**UPDATE**

You also have a problem with the cursor position. You can solve this by using this jQuery plugin [acdvorak/jquery.caret](https://github.com/acdvorak/jquery.caret) to set the caret position to the beggining of the input each time characters are typed like this:

```
$(this).val(numeral($(this).val()).format('0,0.00$'));
$(this).caret(0);
```

Also, I have included the language in input's data like `data-language="sk"` and now you can read it directly in the `keyup` event like this:

```
numeral.language($(this).data('language'));
```

See my updated snippet. It should now works as you want.

Comment: strange, I can't normally enter numbers into first field? https://gyazo.com/b208be037e9ad619a6d82d8d73b88975

Comment: When you want the number formatting to apply? You have it triggered to the first input `keyup` event. Then when you hit keys on the first field, the cursor goes at the end of the newly applies string, because that's how text inputs are working. Also the second input does not update the formatting until you hit keys on the first input. What exact behavior you want to have here?

Comment: Hmmm. I want to format input number instantly, when I type. Not the keyup function is what I am looking for?